# How to use Project Lombok with Java project

Tags: java, lombok

I want to try out [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) specifically the `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@Getter`, `@Setter`

However when I try to use it and do something like:

```
User user = new User(); // error, even if User have @NoArgsConstructor annotation
```

Am I missing something here?

**Error:**

```
The constructor User() is undefined
```

Comment: Please tell us a little bit more about your environment. How are you compiling your code? Are you using an IDE, and if so, which one?

Comment: The constructor User() is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed Lombok and added it to your pom file?

See:
http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJan2010.html#installation